# PowerShell 'get-ClusterQuorum' output is not showing 'QuorumType' column

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell

PowerShell cmdlet 'get-ClusterQuorum' output is not showing "QuorumType" column. Has anybody seen this before? Thanks

Comment: What Windows ? Did u tired spec cluster name like Get-ClusterQuorum -Cluster Cluster1  ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the default formatting for the output of that command has been modified. You can override the default formatting with the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

```
Get-ClusterQuorum | Select-Object Cluster, QuorumResource, QuorumType
```

Using that command will ensure that those three columns are outputted to the console.